# Recovering files from a flash drive when System Volume Information has been deleted

Tags: data-recovery, usb-drive

I have a 16 GB FAT32 pendrive. I accidentally formatted it on Ubuntu 16.04 and lost the System Volume Information directory. After that my pendrive has become inaccessible.

Please help me to recover the information from my pendrive and make it usable.

Comment: Try with `testdisk` and follow [these steps](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). Good Luck.